# Powershell Script "$_.FullName" not working - Sending files via "Copy-VMFile"

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm trying to use a script I found on the internet to copy all files in a directory but I can't get it to work. Can anybody help debug? I'm guessing the script was used to transfer windows/windows but I need windows --> Linux.

https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/12/17/pstip-copying-folders-using-copy-vmfile-cmdlet-in-windows-server-2012-r2-hyper-v/

```
Get-ChildItem C:\tmp -Recurse -File | % { Copy-VMFile -Name "OpenProject8.3" -SourcePath $_.FullName -DestinationPath "/tmp/" -FileSource Host }
```

The issue seems to be related to the sourcepath, but im not 100%.

```
Copy-VMFile : Failed to initiate copying files to the guest.
Failed to copy the source file 'C:\tmp\svn-repositories-20200212010002.tar.gz' to the destination '/tmp/' in the guest.
At line:1 char:43
+ ... -File | % { Copy-VMFile -Name "OpenProject8.3" -SourcePath $_.FullNam ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-VMFile], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.CopyVMFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.... I feel stupid! The issue was that earlier testing the x-fer had succeeded and then when the file exists, Copy-VMFile won't overwrite the file (even though it uses root account...) and gives a non-descriptive error! The code above works fine as is.